# Error 400 when trying sending form data via pos

Tags: javascript, json

Folks

I've a problem with error 400 when trying sending form data via post.
But I can't find in where is the error:

localhost maybe?

```
function sendUser() {
const form = document.getElementById("cad");
if (submit) {
  submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let user = new User(
      form.userProfile.value,
      form.name.value,
      form.lastname.value,
      form.email.value
    );

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/register-user', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).then(function (response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject({
          status: response.status,
          statusText: response.statusText
        });
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
    });
  })
}
```

}

Comment: included the cors headers?

Comment: It can be in the server side while handling the request please do check that as well.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't see `new Headers()` used in the documentation, maybe try with just a standard object like [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)

Comment: I would echo the 'check server side' comment - Perhaps there is validation there that is rejecting your request - badly formed email / min length etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it using jquery

```
var settings = {
      "url": "http://10.1.2.10:8080/api/auth/register-user",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      },
      "data": JSON.stringify(user)
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```